# replace string only in certain lines containing another string

Tags: xml, awk, replace, sed, gsub

I have a big xml file and I want to replace only `weight="7.0"` to `weight="11.0"` but only in the lines containing `clockRateScaler` like the one below.

```
   <operator id="clockRateScaler." spec="ScaleOperator" parameter="@clockRate.c" scaleFactor="0.5" weight="7.0"/>
```

I tried with `sed`

```
sed 'clockRateScaler/s/ weight="7.0"/ weight="7.0"' file.xml
```

but it didn't work.

How could I do this under awk or sed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using `sed`

```
sed '/clockRateScaler/s/weight="7.0"/weight="11.0"/g' file.xml
```

using `awk`

```
awk '/clockRateScaler/{gsub("weight=\"7.0\"", "weight=\"11.0\"")}1' file.xml
```

or using `xmlstarlet` (better)

```
xmlstarlet ed -u '/operator[@id="clockRateScaler."]/@weight' -v 11.0 file.xml
```

you get,

```
<operator id="clockRateScaler." spec="ScaleOperator" parameter="@clockRate.c" scaleFactor="0.5" weight="11.0"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to replace `weight="7.0"` with the same string and you missed some `/`.

You should try the command:

```
sed '/clockRateScaler/s/weight="7.0"/weight="11.0"/' file.xml
```